# Displaying chat messages of punished users only to themselves

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions, postgresql-14

I have prepared [a simple test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5a21a713d0c62f1da13ef813e5668fa) for my question.

In [an online word game for 2 players](https://wordsbyfarber.com/en) based on PostgreSQL 14.2, when someone is misbehaving I set their "muted" column to "true".

Then the chat messages coming from the punished users should be hidden to everyone else.

Except for the punished users themselves  - they should see all the chat messages, so that they do not notice that they are muted and do not create new game accounts.

I already do this trick for their avatars

So I have prepared a simple test case, here are my 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE words_users (
    uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    muted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false
);

CREATE TABLE words_social (
    -- social network id
    sid     text     NOT NULL CHECK (sid ~ '\S'),
    -- social network type: 100 = Facebook, 200 = Google, etc.
    social  integer  NOT NULL CHECK (0 < social AND social <= 256),
    given   text     NOT NULL CHECK (given ~ '\S'),
    uid     integer  NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(sid, social)
);

CREATE TABLE words_games (
    gid      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    player1  integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL CHECK (player1 <> player2),
    player2  integer REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE words_chat (
    cid     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL,
    gid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_games ON DELETE CASCADE,
    uid     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES words_users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    msg     text    NOT NULL
);
```

Then I fill the tables with the test data:

```
-- create 2 users: one is ok, while the other is muted (punished)
INSERT INTO words_users (uid, muted) VALUES (1, false), (2, true);
INSERT INTO words_social (sid, social, given, uid) VALUES ('abc', 100, 'Nice user', 1), ('def', 200, 'Bad user', 2);

-- put these 2 users into a game number 10
INSERT INTO words_games (gid, player1, player2) VALUES (10, 1, 2);

-- start chatting
INSERT INTO words_chat (gid, uid, created, msg) VALUES
(10, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1 min', 'Hi how are you doing?'),
(10, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '2 min', 'I am a nice user'),
(10, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '3 min', 'F*** ***!!'),
(10, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '4 min', 'I am a bad user'),
(10, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5 min','Are you there??');
```

And finally here is the SQL function that I am trying to improve:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_chat(
                in_gid    integer,
                in_social integer,
                in_sid    text
        ) RETURNS TABLE (
                out_mine  integer,
                out_msg   text
        ) AS
$func$
        -- TODO display messages by muted users only to themselves
        SELECT
                CASE WHEN c.uid = s.uid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                c.msg
        FROM    words_chat c 
        JOIN    words_games g USING (gid) 
        JOIN    words_social s ON s.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2)
        WHERE   c.gid    = in_gid
        AND     s.social = in_social
        AND     s.sid    = in_sid
        ORDER BY c.CREATED ASC;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT words_get_chat(10, 100, 'abc') AS nice_user;

SELECT words_get_chat(10, 200, 'def') AS muted_user;
```

Currently the stored function displays all chat messages, but I would like to hide messages coming from muted players for everyone else (shown by red lines in the screenshot below):

[image: screenshot]

Please help me to improve my SQL function and note that I do not want to switch to PL/pgSQL for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Daniel's sub query answer and help at the PostgreSQL mailing list, I have developed [a CTE and JOIN solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0bd710e1d90c2e5c92256e97d7ddfdd2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_chat(
                in_gid    integer,
                in_social integer,
                in_sid    text
        ) RETURNS TABLE (
                out_mine  integer,
                out_msg   text
        ) AS
$func$
        WITH myself AS (
            SELECT uid 
            FROM words_social
            WHERE social = in_social
            AND sid = in_sid
        )
        SELECT
                CASE WHEN c.uid = myself.uid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                c.msg
        FROM    words_chat c
        JOIN    myself ON TRUE
        JOIN    words_games g USING (gid) 
        JOIN    words_users opponent ON (opponent.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2) AND opponent.uid <> myself.uid)
        WHERE   c.gid = in_gid
        -- always show myself my own chat messages
        AND     (c.uid = myself.uid 
        -- otherwise only show messages by not muted opponents
                 OR NOT opponent.muted)
        ORDER BY c.created ASC;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Also I received a nice recommendation [to separate auth logic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0bd710e1d90c2e5c92256e97d7ddfdd2) from my game's logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_uid(
                in_social integer,
                in_sid    text
        ) RETURNS integer AS
$func$
        SELECT uid 
        FROM words_social
        WHERE social = in_social
        AND sid = in_sid;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_chat(
                in_gid   integer,
                in_uid   integer
        ) RETURNS TABLE (
                out_mine integer,
                out_msg  text
        ) AS
$func$
        SELECT
                CASE WHEN c.uid = in_uid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                c.msg
        FROM    words_chat c
        JOIN    words_games g USING (gid) 
        JOIN    words_users opponent ON (opponent.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2) AND opponent.uid <> in_uid)
        WHERE   c.gid = in_gid
        -- always show myself my own chat messages
        AND     (c.uid = in_uid 
        -- otherwise only show messages by not muted opponents
                 OR NOT opponent.muted)
        ORDER BY c.created ASC;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT words_get_chat(10, words_get_uid(100, 'abc')) AS nice_user;

SELECT words_get_chat(10, words_get_uid(200, 'def')) AS muted_user;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand correctly, you can try to use `EXISTS` subquery to judgment mute user in `words_get_chat` function by your logic.

- if nice user we need to judgment which message they want to see.
- if bad user we can show all of message.

The function might look like as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_chat(
        in_gid    integer,
        in_social integer,
        in_sid    text
) RETURNS TABLE (
        out_msg   text
) AS
$func$
-- TODO display messages by muted users only to themselves
SELECT
        c.msg
FROM    words_chat c 
JOIN    words_games g USING (gid) 
JOIN    words_social s ON s.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2)
WHERE   c.gid    = in_gid
AND     s.social = in_social
AND     s.sid    = in_sid
AND     EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM words_users wu
       WHERE wu.uid = s.uid AND 
       ((muted = true) OR (muted = false AND c.uid = s.uid))
)
ORDER BY c.CREATED ASC;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2ea95ec625bfa7dd33710daa17b5756e)

Comment: Thanks it works as expected, but I am struggling to understand your sub-query... I have around 50 000 users in my game (not every user record is an active player, but still...), would it fetch all of them by the sub-query? How to limit it only to the 2 players in the game? (because I do not see that limitation/restriction).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I think that can be work if the conversation is one on one I try to add more sample data for that https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=524a1fce8abd4f96719538ba73de76d1

Comment: This join condition `ON s.uid IN (g.player1, g.player2)` might limit only to the 2 players in the game I think

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't think your solution is correct, because when you try a chat of two not-muted users - then [they will only see their own messages](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eea148c2bafdd97a2e7132949f8722c7)